# How to read toml file in Ballerina?

Tags: ballerina, toml

I have some resource files that are in `toml` format. What is the approach to read a toml file using ballerina language? Also, is there a module for `toml` for the basic file read/write operations?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the ballerina [toml module](https://ballerina.io/spec/toml/) to read/write toml files.

Ex:

```ballerina
import ballerina/toml;
// Parsing a TOML file
map<json>|toml:Error tomlFile = toml:readFile("path/to/file.toml");

// Write the TOML content into a file
map<json> toml = {
    "str": "string",
    "float": 0.01,
    "inline": {
        "boolean": false
    }
};
toml:Error? fileResult = toml:writeFile("path/to/file.toml", toml);
```

For more details, refer to the [API docs](https://central.ballerina.io/ballerina/toml/latest).